# Facebook Login example runtime exception

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio

My facebook login application fails with the following runtime error:

```html
07-31 12:47:10.195    1309-1316/com.android.quicksearchbox E/jdwp﹕ Failed writing handshake bytes: Broken pipe (-1 of 14)
07-31 12:47:11.004    1341-1358/com.example.apurva.myapplication E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider
07-31 12:47:11.094    1341-1360/com.example.apurva.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.containsKey(ConcurrentHashMap.java:781)
            at com.facebook.internal.Utility.queryAppSettings(Utility.java:802)
            at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton$1.doInBackground(LoginButton.java:502)
            at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton$1.doInBackground(LoginButton.java:499)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

A few pointers on what I have done till now:
1)Followed all the requirements in Facebook's Getting Started post.
2)Added the meta-data to the XML.
3)Added the key-hash to facebook

If you see any particular files that might be causing the problem and want to see it before answering, do let me know.

Comment: thats a **NullPointerException**. post your **doInBackground** method

Comment: Where is the doInBackGround located?

Comment: you are using an **AsyncTask** right??

Comment: You are getting this error at some point of running your application. please explain that and post some relevant codes.

Comment: What version of the SDK is this?